# Is there a way to collapse or group children nodes in d3 tree layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scenario where the tree layout may have a node that has more than 80 nodes.
For example -

Parent (circular node) - Child (circular node )- 100s of children nodes (100s of circular nodes).
Is there a way i can group the 100s of nodes into a group or a chart and then have that chart display instead of node image at the end of the tree ?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html, you can collapse/expand nodes with children

Comment: Hi, 
I already have a expand or collapse on click in my tree layout. 
For example if the end node has around 50 nodes , i would like to make it into a pie chart or a bubble chart saying - of the 50 children nodes - 20 are of type A , 20 are B and 10 are C.. 
Now this bubble chart should show up at the end of the node instead of 50 children nodes

Comment: got it, I misunderstood it. You can define arbitrary symbols as nodes. So, yes you can have a pie chart at whichever level/depth you'd like. You can traverse the tree as in https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-hierarchy. Share your code so we can guide you better.